# EasyAR sdk with Intel Realsense SDK issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting this error in my project using intel realsense sdk and EasyAR sdk both at the same time. My idea is to augment a 3D object and move it using intel realsense camera Hand Gesture Tracking. Please help.

> > NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object UnityEditor.DockArea.OnGUI () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/DockArea.cs:272) PXCMSenseManager:PXCMSenseManager_Init(IntPtr, IntPtr) PXCMSenseManager:Init(Handler) PXCMSenseManager:Init() EasyAR.RealityPlaneBehaviour:Start() (at Assets/EasyAR/Scripts/RealityPlaneBehaviour.cs:51)**

I am using a Sample Code provided by both SDKS. Merged them in one
project. I am successful in Augmenting the 3D object but not able to
move the 3D object by Hand gesture tracking.

This is the code I am using:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace EasyAR
{
    public class RealityPlaneBehaviour : RealityPlaneBaseBehaviour
    {

        public GameObject Paddle1;
        public GameObject Paddle2;
        private PXCMSenseManager _pxcmSenseManager;
        private PXCMHandModule _pxcmHandModule;
        private PXCMHandData handData;
        private pxcmStatus status;

        // Use this for initialization
        private void Start()
        {
            _pxcmSenseManager = PXCMSenseManager.CreateInstance();


            if (_pxcmSenseManager == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SenseManager Initialization Failed");
            }
            else
            {
                //pxcmStatus pxcmResult = _pxcmSenseManager.EnableHand();
                pxcmStatus pxcmResult = _pxcmSenseManager.EnableHand();
                if (pxcmResult != pxcmStatus.PXCM_STATUS_NO_ERROR)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("EnableHand: " + pxcmResult);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Reached Here:1 " + pxcmResult);
                    _pxcmHandModule = _pxcmSenseManager.QueryHand();
                    Debug.LogError("Reached Here:1 " + _pxcmHandModule.ToString());
                    handData = _pxcmHandModule.CreateOutput();
                    Debug.LogError("Reached Here:1 " + handData.ToString());
                    if(_pxcmHandModule == null)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("PxcmHandModule is null during Setup");
                        return;
                    }   
                    _pxcmSenseManager.Init();

                    PXCMHandConfiguration configuration = _pxcmHandModule.CreateActiveConfiguration();
                    configuration.EnableAllGestures();
                    configuration.ApplyChanges();
                    configuration.Dispose();



                }
            }
        }


        // Update is called once per frame
        private void Update()
        {
            if (_pxcmSenseManager == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("PxcmSenseManager is null");
                return;
            }

            _pxcmSenseManager.AcquireFrame(false, 0);

            status = _pxcmSenseManager.AcquireFrame(true);
            if (status != pxcmStatus.PXCM_STATUS_NO_ERROR) 
                return;

            _pxcmHandModule = _pxcmSenseManager.QueryHand();
            if(_pxcmHandModule == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("PxcmHandModule is null");
                return;
            }   

            PXCMHandData handData = _pxcmHandModule.CreateOutput();
            handData.Update();

            MoveBall(handData, PXCMHandData.AccessOrderType.ACCESS_ORDER_LEFT_HANDS, Paddle1);
            MoveBall(handData, PXCMHandData.AccessOrderType.ACCESS_ORDER_RIGHT_HANDS, Paddle2);

            _pxcmSenseManager.ReleaseFrame();
        }

        private void MoveBall(PXCMHandData handData, PXCMHandData.AccessOrderType accessOrderType, GameObject gameObject)
        {
            // Get first hand data (index 0),
            PXCMHandData.IHand pxcmHandData;


            if (handData.QueryHandData(accessOrderType, 0, out pxcmHandData) == pxcmStatus.PXCM_STATUS_NO_ERROR)
            {
                PXCMHandData.JointData jointData;
                if (pxcmHandData.QueryTrackedJoint(PXCMHandData.JointType.JOINT_CENTER, out jointData) ==
                    pxcmStatus.PXCM_STATUS_NO_ERROR)
                {   
                    gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(-9, jointData.positionWorld.y*100f, 0);
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnDisable()
        {
            _pxcmHandModule.Dispose();
            _pxcmSenseManager.Dispose();
        }







    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell us which line is line 51. I see you use `_pxcmHandModule` before checking if it is `null`, which might be a problem - now I think about it, calling `QueryHand()` and `CreateOutput()` before `Init()` also seems suspicious.

Comment: _pxcmSenseManager.Init(); this is line 51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a read/write issue because when Realsense SDK is installed, it is installed in a protected directory(`C:/Program Files`) you usually don't have permission to write to.

Re-install the Realsense SDK but this time, change the install directory to `C:/RealsenseSDK`. The permission problem should be gone and you won't be getting Object reference exception anymore.

Comment: I did that now its throwing this error : SenseManager Initialization Failed
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
EasyAR.RealityPlaneBehaviour:Start() (at Assets/EasyAR/Scripts/RealityPlaneBehaviour.cs:29)

Comment: This solution was meant to solve the `NullReferenceException` error and it did. The current error you are now getting now is totally different and I may not be able to help any further...Why not unplug and plug the camera to a diffrent USB hub?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Programmer.I solved the other one.